# Char equivalent for Tabstop

Tags: c#, string, char

I want to split a string with Tabstops. What is the correct char[] equivalent for usage with

```
Split.(char[] x, int i)
```

Comment: `````'\t'`````?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, you should put that as an answer as it is entirely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
var output = input.Split('\t');
```

This will split the `input` string into an array of `string`'s, separated by tab characters.

**Further reading:**

- [Character literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above 
[ControlChars.Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.aspx)

Comment: Which sits in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Comment: could have been a comment

Comment: Absolutely right  Tim Schmelter